# Android - Dismiss/Hide does not dismiss the dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm Using Dialogname.Show() method to show a loading dialog this is working fine however when I try to dismiss it it does not work I have used Dialogname.hide(), Dialogname.cancel(), Dialogname.dismiss()

**Dialog is an acitivity**

```
public class RecipeLoading extends Dialog {
public RecipeLoading(@NonNull Context context){
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.meetvishalkumar.myapplication.R.layout.activity_recipe_loading);
}
```

}

**Dialog Dismiss Code**
`

```
RecipeLoading recipeLoading = new RecipeLoading(RecipeDetailsActivity.this);
recipeLoading.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
recipeLoading.hide();
recipeLoading.cancel();
recipeLoading.dismiss();
```

`

**Dialog Show Code**

`

```
RecipeLoading recipeLoading = new RecipeLoading(RecipeDetailsActivity.this);
recipeLoading.setCancelable(false);
recipeLoading.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
recipeLoading.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
recipeLoading.show();
```

`

i'm Using Dialogname.Show() method to show a loading dialog this is working fine however when i try to dismiss it it does not work i have used Dialogname.hide(), Dialogname.cancel(), Dialogname.dismiss()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your calling `RecipeLoading recipeLoading = new RecipeLoading(RecipeDetailsActivity.this);` in the second time, your living the previous `recipeLoading` and calling a new one and when you calling the `recipeLoading.dismiss();` you basically calling to dismiss the second `recipeLoading` that you created (who haven't shown yet)

so i suggest you to declare at the top of your class
and create it whenever you want to show it and then when you want to dismiss it just call `recipeLoading.dismiss();`

your code should look like this:

```
public class RecipeDetailsActivity extends Activity {
    
    // diclaring a RecipeLoading named "recipeLoading"
    RecipeLoading recipeLoading;

    // onCreate() etc.
}
```

when you want to show the dialog just call

```
recipeLoading = new RecipeLoading(this);
recipeLoading.show();
```

and to dismiss it call

```
recipeLoading.dismiss();
```

to keep things more organized do all the dialog customizations inside the dialog class, like this:

```
public class RecipeLoading extends Dialog {
    public RecipeLoading(@NonNull Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.meetvishalkumar.myapplication.R.layout.activity_recipe_loading);

        setCancelable(false);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is First you create an object of dialog and show it (Good)

Now when you try to dismiss it you create a new object of dialog again and then try to hide it instead of calling the hide or dismiss or cancel method of the old object of dialog, try like this for showing

```
RecipeLoading recipeLoading = new RecipeLoading(RecipeDetailsActivity.this);
recipeLoading.setCancelable(false);
recipeLoading.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
recipeLoading.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
recipeLoading.show();
```

now when you want to dismiss it use

```
recipeLoading.dismiss();
```

it will dismiss the dialog which is being shown

Comment: it wont work cause dialog is an Lottie animation and it's an activity

This is the code for dialog 
public class RecipeLoading extends Dialog {
    public RecipeLoading(@NonNull Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.meetvishalkumar.myapplication.R.layout.activity_recipe_loading);
    }
}

Comment: if i removed this line "RecipeLoading recipeLoading = new RecipeLoading(RecipeDetailsActivity.this);"
 it would give an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'recipeLoading' "

Comment: The first thing your RecipeLoading is not an activity it is a Custom Dialog
Next, you are getting error because recipeLoading is not in scope where you are trying to access it.